# Inserting record in Entity Framework without Foreign Key References

Tags: entity-framework

Please see below my ERD. Both Company and Contact can have ContactDetails and be Users at the same time. As such I haven't explicitly defined foreign key relationships with these tables. I user UserType (int) to determine whether it is Company or Contact and then store the relevant ID in the EntityId field.
[image]

Here is the code snippet I use to insert a new Company in the database.

```
    public ActionResult Create(ProjectUser user)
    {                
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (user.UserType == (int)PC.Utils.Enums.UserType.Company)
            {
                Company company = user.GetCompany();            // Get Company UI values from View Model

                ContactDetail detail = user.GetContactDetail(); // Get Contact UI values from View Model
                detail.UserType = (int)UserType.Company;        // bind contact Type to Company Type
                detail.EntityId = company.Id;                   

                User login = user.GetLoginDetails();                    // Get User UI values from View Model
                login.UserType = (int)UserType.Company;                 // bind User Login to Company
                login.EntityId = company.Id;
                login.Password = PC.Utils.Security.GetMD5Hash(login.Password);  // encrypt the password
                db.Companies.Add(company);
                db.ContactDetails.Add(detail);
                db.Users.Add(login);
                db.SaveChanges();


            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

However, when I check the database the EntityId in both Users and ContactDetails table is 0, as EF did not determine the correct ID in the transaction. Is there something I am missing, or is there a nicer way to achieve this?